# Redis-server is in slave mode on startup

Tags: redis, configuration, debian

I'm trying to create a one-master one-slave redis system.
I noticed that my master node is starting as a slave:

```
1) "slave"
2) "no"
3) (integer) 0
4) "connect"
5) (integer) -1
```

Why is this? Is this how it should work?

I tried stopping the slave node then starting the master but it still act as slave unless I run redis-cli slaveof no one.

My redis.conf:

```
bind 0.0.0.0 ::1
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize yes
supervised no
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
loglevel notice
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
databases 16
always-show-logo yes
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /var/lib/redis
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only no
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4096
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
maxmemory 200mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lfu
replicaof no one
slaveof no one
```

Comment: Can you run "INFO REPLICATION" on the master node and show the output?

Comment: I have removed the repilcaof/slaveof no one lines from the configuration and it solved the problem.